# Row totals based on column name in PowerQuery

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a data file with around 400 columns in it. I need to import this data into PowerPivot. In order to reduce my file size, I would like to use PowerQuery to create 2 different **row totals**, and then delete all my unneeded columns upon load.

While my first row total column (RowTotal1) would summate all 400 columns, I would also like a second row total (RowTotal2) that subtracts from RowTotal1 any column whose name **contains the text "click"** in it.

Secondly, I would like to use the the value in my Country column as a variable, to also subtract any column that contains this var. e.g.

**Site**----**Country**----**Col1**----**Col2**----**ClickCol1**----**Col3**----**Germany**----**RowTotal1**----**RowTotal2**

1a--------USA----------2---------4-----------8------------16----------24--------------54---------------46-------

2a-----Germany-------2---------4-----------8------------16----------24--------------54---------------22-------

RowTotal1 = 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 24

RowTotal2 *(first row)* = 54 - 8 *(ClickCol1)*

RowTotal2 *(second row)* = 54 - 24 *(Germany)* - 8 *(ClickCol1)*

Is this possible? (**EDIT**: Yes. See answer below)

**REVISED QUESTION:** Is there a more memory efficient way to do than trying to group 300+ million rows at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code would look something like this:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Site", type text}, {"Country", type text}, {"Col1", Int64.Type}, {"Col2", Int64.Type}, {"ClickCol1", Int64.Type}, {"Col3", Int64.Type}, {"Germany", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Country", "Site"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Value2", each if [Country] = [Attribute] or [Attribute] = "ClickCol1" then 0 else [Value] ),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Conditional Column", {"Site", "Country"}, {{"RowTotal1", each List.Sum([Value]), type number},{"RowTotal2", each List.Sum([Value2]), type number}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

But since you have a lot of columns, I should explain the steps:

- (Assuming you have these in Excel file) Import them to Power Query
- Select "Site" and "Country" columns (with Ctrl), right click > Unpivot Other Columns
- Add Column with this formula (you might need to use Advanced Editor): Table.AddColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Value2", each if [Country] = [Attribute] or [Attribute] = "ClickCol1" then 0 else [Value])
- Select Site and Country columns, Right Click > Group By
- Make it look like this: [image]

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Just arrived at the same conclusion and was about to update the post. The only problem I am facing is that unpivoted, each month contains around 16 million rows. In total, my data analysis has around 24 months. While PowerQuery is quick at unpivoting, grouping around 380 million rows by 6 columns times it out. I will vote your answer up as technically it answers the question, but will leave the answer unsolved as I'm hoping for a more memory efficient way to do this. (Excel x64 with 8Gb RAM)

Comment: I'm not sure it can be done faster.. Maybe you can define a function that will do this, but will have some filters. Or, you could group things at a larger step to make the inner steps smaller. Like, you could group the rows on an outer level for each month for example?

Comment: (you would pick "All Rows" operation when you're grouping the months on the outer side)

Comment: Hmmm, all good ideas. Unfortunately 'm not super comfortable with creating my own functions in M yet, but will give it a go. Alternatively, your grouping by larger steps makes a lot of sense. Will shake the tree (so to speak), and see what comes out. Thanks again!

Comment: This https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2013/08/19/creating-power-query-functions/ has a nice explanation & example for creating your own M functions :)